# mysqli asynchronous requests with a parameterized query

Tags: php, asynchronous, mysqli, mariadb, paramterized

I'm doing 1-n asynchronously request from php 8.1 to maria-db using mysqli_poll. Works perfectly.

As far as I know I can only set up the sql query using the query() function because it has the MYSQLI_ASYNC constant as the second parameter. But I prefer to create the sql statement with a parameterized query and then request also asynchronously.

Does it also work with prepare(..) and execute(..) and mysqli_poll ?
Where to set the asynchronous state at the mysqli-connection with that approach because mysqli_polls refers to a collection of connections and not executed statements..

Comment: _"Does it also work with prepare(..) and execute(..)"_... a quick scan through the documentation suggests _no_.

Comment: The short answer is No. According to the internals, the only usage of `MYSQLI_ASYNC` is within the `mysqli_query` function.